# Define item thumbnail background color as white in WooCommerce email notifications

Tags: php, html, css, woocommerce, email-notifications

I would like to change the background color of the product thumbnails that the customer receives via WooCommerce email.
Is it possible to add a css to do this without modifying the original PNGs of the product photos? as a matter of design I would like to maintain the transparencies.

This is what I applied to my PHP to show the thumbnail:

```php
add_filter( 'woocommerce_email_order_items_args', 'custom_email_order_items_args', 10, 1 );
function custom_email_order_items_args( $args ) {
    $args['show_image'] = true;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

**Update** *(see below)*

You can use the following hooked function, to set thumbnail product backgound color to white:

```php
add_filter( 'woocommerce_email_styles', 'custom_wc_email_styles', 1000 );
function custom_wc_email_styles( $css ) {
    $css .= '.order_item > td > img { background-color: #ffffff; }';

    return $css;
}
```

Code goes in functions.php file of your child theme (or in a plugin). Tested and works.

---

**Important Note:**

On your question code there is something missing… Use the following instead:

```php
add_filter( 'woocommerce_email_order_items_args', 'custom_email_order_items_args', 10, 1 );
function custom_email_order_items_args( $args ) {
    $args['show_image'] = true;

    return $args; // <== Mandatory (was missing)
}
```